# Is there a std::set function for determining the largest element that does not exceed a number x?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I read online that an `std::set` has useful member functions that can help search for elements.

Specifically,

`std::set::lower_bound`, which returns an iterator to the smallest element that is >= a number x, and
`std::set::upper_bound`, which returns an iterator to the smallest element that exceeds x.

However, I want to find a function that returns an iterator to the *largest* element that does not exceed x. Is there such a function in C++?

Comment: Unless `std::lower_bound` returned `begin()`, you can use `std::prev` to move to the node's predecessor.

Comment: if (x < *begin) you want to return end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decrement the iterator returned from upper_bound:

```
std::set<int> s;
s.insert(3);
s.insert(4);
s.insert(5);
s.insert(7);

auto itor = s.upper_bound(6);
if (itor != s.begin())
{
    --itor;
    std::cout << *itor << std::endl;
}
```

The above should print "5"